# PIC for ENC28J60

Tags: microcontroller, pic, c, ethernet

I am beginner in the microcontroller world, I started to work with PIC MCUs and writing simple programs in assembly. I am interested in simple controlling via LAN (such as switching LED on/off). I've got PIC16f877A on my development board and microchip ethernet interface ENC28J60.

So, can use those two components together for some simple application?

Comment: Are you asking if the PIC16F877A can be used with an ENC28J60?

Comment: Yes, and how to connect?

Comment: it uses SPI, you can find example schematics a number of places including the datasheet http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/39662a.pdf

Comment: Thanks, this is new for me and any information is helpful

Answer (score 3):

The ancient 16F877A is not a good choice if you want to be a regular network citizen.  It has too little code space to do a proper TCP implementation and still have anything left over for the application.  It could be OK if you just want to transmit and receive network packets using your own protocol.

However, there are newer chips that cost the same or less than the 16F877A and are far more capable.  I'd look into the 18F67J60.  It has lots more code space, more RAM, and comes with the ENC28J60 built in.  You can do a full TCP stack and still have something like 85% of the code space left over for the application.  It is probably cheaper and is certainly smaller and more capable than the 16F877A and ENC28J60 together.

Comment: I is not about cost, only problem is I need to order chip from net. I was thinking to use chips I already have. So is it looks like is better to buy something what is more simple to work with because I am beginner